# I want to remove firebase from my Xcode project installed with cocoapods

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods-app

I want to remove firebase from my Xcode project installed with cocoapods
how to manage
thanks for your answer

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to your Podfile and remove the line `pod 'Firebase/Core'`, and any other firebase lines. Then in your terminal run `pod install`

Comment: Thanks a lot it Works !

Comment: This has not been working for me at all. I have been trying everything and have had 0 success with updating. I have thi sone line of code which keeps giving me an error because the project thinks i am using one coocoapod over another (I accidentali inputed teh wronf one)